# Simplify a large expression

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I'm a computational, high-speed aerodynamics student. I came up with the next function (that defines the top surface of a wing):

$f = C\cdot h(a,b,n)=C\cdot (ab)^{n-1}(b-a)$

Upon derivation I get:

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}=C\cdot \dfrac{\partial h(a,b,n)}{\partial x}$

Where:

$\dfrac{\partial h(a,b,n)}{\partial x} = C\cdot\left[\underbrace{(n-1)a^{n-2}b^{n-1}(b-a)-(n-1)a^{n-1}b^{n-2}(b-a)-2a^{n-1}b^{n-1}}_{\text{g(a,b,n): this ugly expression needs to be simplified somehow.}}\right]$

I need a much more manageable expression (it is supposed to be displayed in a PowerPoint presentation; furthermore it's supposed to be embedded in an aerodynamics text, so I need an elegant expression).

Ideas?

Comment: Edited the formula. Now it's all correct.

Comment: It looks like you have an explicit expression for $h(a,b,n)$ which it would help to show. It also looks like you are missing $\frac {\partial a}{\partial x}$ and similar terms. The expression you show doesn't look too tough for PowerPoint to me and certainly not too tough for a text.

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are linear in x. Added the $h(a,b,n)$ function. Do you think it's tough to reduce the expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do $$(n-1)a^{n-2}b^{n-1}(b-a)-(n-1)a^{n-1}b^{n-2}(b-a)-2a^{n-1}b^{n-1}\\=a^{n-2}b^{n-2}\left((n-1)b(b-a)-(n-1)a(b-a)-2ab\right)\\
=a^{n-2}b^{n-2}\left((n-1)(b-a)^2-2ab\right)$$

Comment: Or you can write last bracket as $(b-a)^2n-b^2-a^2$

Comment: Beauty at its finest. My final document says thank you for your time!

Comment: I don't know if this helps the questioner, but using $(a-b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab,$ we have $-2ab = (a-b)^2 - a^2 - b^{2}.$ This allows $(n-1)(b-a)^2 - 2ab$ to be written as $n(a-b)^2 - a^2 - b^{2}.$ (And after getting this all typed out, I see that @Lale221 has beat me to this!)

Comment: It does help, Lale and Dave. But I prefer Ross final expression because it has 2 addends instead of 3!

Comment: But $\partial_xa=1$, $\partial_xb=-1$. The function itself is correct (n doesn't change with x).

Comment: No Ross, because those signs were after unwrapping $1$ and $-1$ :P

Comment: Thanks for your time Ross. It's much appreciated (and sorry for the confusion on that partial derivative with respect x, I should have written it clearer)